# UnicodeDecodeError error with every urllib.request

Tags: python, utf-8, urllib

When I use urllib in Python3 to get the HTML code of a web page, I use this code:

```
def getHTML(url):
    request = Request(url)
    request.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')
    html = urlopen(request).read().decode('utf-8')
    print(html)
    return html
```

However, this fails every time with the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/chris/Documents/Code/Python/HLTV Parser/getTeams.py", line 56, in <module>
getHTML('https://www.hltv.org/team/7900/spirit-academy')
  File "/Users/chris/Documents/Code/Python/HLTV Parser/getTeams.py", line 53, in getHTML
print(html)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 10636-10638: ordinal not in range(128)
[Finished in 1.14s]
```

The [page](https://www.hltv.org/team/7900/spirit-academy) is in UTF-8 and I am decoding it properly according to the urllib docs. The page is not gzipped or in another charset from what I can tell.

`url.info().get_charset()` returns `None` for the page, however the meta tags specify UTF-8. I have no problems viewing the HTML in any program.

I do not want to use any external libraries.

Is there a solution? What is going on? This works fine with the following Python2 code:

```
def getHTML(url):
    opener = urllib2.build_opener()
    opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
    response = opener.open(url)
    html = response.read()
    return html
```

Comment: It worked fine with me... `getHTML('https://www.hltv.org/team/7900/spirit-academy')`, for the first version, with **both** python 2 and 3. Don't know why you're getting different results

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/HLTV Parser/getTeams.py", line 56, in <module>
    getHTML('https://www.hltv.org/team/7900/spirit-academy')
  File "/HLTV Parser/getTeams.py", line 53, in getHTML
    print(html)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 10636-10638: ordinal not in range(128)
[Finished in 1.14s]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `decode('utf-8')`

The following should return the fetched html.

```
def getHTML(url):
    request = Request(url)
    request.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')
    html = urlopen(request).read()
    return html
```

Comment: This won't work since I need to parse the HTML later, and you cannot do regular expression on a bytes-like object.

Comment: @ChrisSardegna actually, yes you can. try it... `re.findall(b'hello', b'hello world')`

Comment: When I do that I get the following error: `TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object`.

Comment: note both the regex and the match recipient has the prefix `b`, you didn't include the `b` for the regex part

Answer (score 0):

There, found your error, the parsing was done just fine, everything was evaluated alright. But when you read the Traceback carefully:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File 
"/Users/chris/Documents/Code/Python/HLTV Parser/getTeams.py", line 56, in <module> 
 getHTML('hltv.org/team/7900/spirit-academy') File 
"/Users/chris/Documents/Code/Python/HLTV Parser/getTeams.py", line 53, in getHTML 
 print(html) 
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 10636-10638: ordinal not in range(128) 
[Finished in 1.14s]
```

The error was caused by the `print` statement, as you can see, this is in the traceback `print(html)`.

---

This is somewhat common exception, it's just telling you that with your current system encoding, some of the text cannot be printed to the console. One simple solution will be to add `print(html.encode('ascii', 'ignore'))` to ignore all the unprintable characters. You still can do all the other stuff with `html`, it's just that you can't print it.

See this if you want a better "fix": https://wiki.python.org/moin/PrintFails

btw: `re` module **can** search byte strings. Copy this exactly as-is, *will* work:

```
import re
print(re.findall(b'hello', b'hello world'))
```

Comment: Adding `'ignore'` does not fix the issue and I still cannot print the HTML.

Comment: Add these in the beginning, each on separate lines`import sys`
`import codecs`
`sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stdout)`